# Correct way to handle changeable queries in PDO?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am currently building a news website that has features such as posting content, labeling the content into categories and voting.

I have gotten to the stage where I am making a home feed for my users, this will show the newest posts but I want to give my users the ability to sort by categories.

Here is my current query

```
SELECT p.*, 
             (SELECT Count(id) 
                    FROM   comments AS c 
                    WHERE  c.post = p.id) AS commentCount,
                    v.type AS vote_type,
             (SELECT Count(id) 
                    FROM   votes AS vo
                    WHERE  vo.post_id = p.id) AS totalVotes
FROM   posts AS p
LEFT JOIN tagged AS t 
            ON p.id = t.post_id
LEFT JOIN votes AS v
            ON v.post_id = p.id
    WHERE (v.user_id = 1 OR v.user_id IS NULL)
    AND t.tag_id = 7
ORDER BY timestamp DESC
LIMIT :limit OFFSET :offset
```

This query has the following parts of code that make it return posts that are only assigned (tagged) with the category id of `7` ( and without these two parts the query becomes the base query I normally use for newest posts)

`LEFT JOIN tagged AS t 
                ON p.id = t.post_id`

`AND t.tag_id = 7`

I was wondering if there is a way to have the base query without the category code and then if needed input the category code rather than have two querys? Is there a way to make a query 'dynamic'.

I want to implement other sorting features but feel creating a bunch of (slightly) different copies of each other would be inefficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, people do this all the time.  You can either dynamically set your parameters, such as in the first example below, or you can dynamically build your SQL statement.  I would think best practice would be to: 1. Make sure it doesn't get too complicated.  At the point that you have a query that is everything to everybody, look at building a query builder or multiple queries.  2. Combine dynamic SQL statements with dynamic parameters.

Prepare your statement:

```
SELECT p.*, 
             (SELECT Count(id) 
                    FROM   comments AS c 
                    WHERE  c.post = p.id) AS commentCount,
                    v.type AS vote_type,
             (SELECT Count(id) 
                    FROM   votes AS vo
                    WHERE  vo.post_id = p.id) AS totalVotes
FROM   posts AS p
LEFT JOIN tagged AS t 
            ON p.id = t.post_id
LEFT JOIN votes AS v
            ON v.post_id = p.id
    WHERE (v.user_id = 1 OR v.user_id IS NULL)
    AND t.tag_id = :tagid
ORDER BY timestamp DESC
LIMIT :limit OFFSET :offset
```

Now bind your element (pseudo code):

```
if( ! isset( $someValue ) ) $someValue = 7; // I am just giving it a default value for 
// an example.  You can do whatever.
pdo->bindParam( ':tagid', $someValue, parameterType such as PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

You can keep building like this, or you can break up your bigger SQL prepared statement.  By way of example:

```
if( $categoryCodeNeeded === true ) // add another and statement to where portion of your sql statement
  $select += " AND tag_id = 7 ";
```

**Edit to answer the question in the comment:**

The code that you provided:  SELECT p.* is either assigned to a variable right now, or it is inside another piece of code that looks like this:

```
$statement = $dbHandler->prepare('SELECT p.* FROM posts p blah blah blah' );
```

If it's the second case, then you can change that line of code to read:

$statement = $dbHandler->prepare( $yourOwnSelectVariable );

Then, you can build your variable however you want.

```
$yourOwnSelectVariable = "SELECT p.* FROM posts p";
if( $categoryCodeNeeded )
    $yourOwnSelectVariable += " WHERE tag_id = :tagid ";
$statement = $dbHandler->prepare( $yourOwnSelectVariable );
if( ! isset( $tagId ) ) $tagId = 7;
    $statement->bindParam( ':tagid', $tagId, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. How would $select be added to the query?

Comment: See the edit.  If you don't understand the edit, then spend a little time reading a "how to use pdo" tutorial.

Comment: I see, so basically build a variable then prepare it.

Comment: Yep, is that what you were looking for?

Comment: Sure is! One last thing, can I use $query->execute(array(':tagid' => $tag)); rather than bindParam?